# Subspace involving matrices product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, vector-spaces

Matrix $A_{\theta}$ is given like this:
$$A_{\theta}=
    \Bigg[{\begin{matrix}
    \cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta}  \\
    \sin{\theta} & \;\;\;\cos{\theta}  \\
    \end{matrix}}\Bigg]
$$

And $M_{\theta}\leq M_2(\mathbb R),$ for some $\theta\in \mathbb F(=\mathbb R).$
$$M_{\theta}=\{X\in M_2(\mathbb R):A_{\theta}\cdot X=X^{\tau}\cdot A_{-\theta}\}.$$

$M_{\theta}\leq M_2(\mathbb R), \forall \theta\in \mathbb R?$ If not, find those which satisfy the constraint.

$M_{\theta}\leq M_2(\mathbb R)\implies :\alpha X_1+\beta X_2\in M_{\theta} \;\forall X_1, X_2 \in M_{\theta},\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb R,$ but I have problems with simplifying the product condition.
I' ve seen the post with proof of two possible ways of rewriting the orthogonal matrices:

$A_{\theta}=
    \Bigg[{\begin{matrix}
    \cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta}  \\
    \sin{\theta} & \;\;\;\cos{\theta}  \\
    \end{matrix}}\Bigg]=
    {\Bigg[{\begin{matrix}
    \cos{\theta} & \;\;\;\sin{\theta}  \\
    \sin{\theta} & -\cos{\theta}  \\
    \end{matrix}}\Bigg]},
$ for $x\in[0,2\pi].$

I got:

$$A_{-{\theta}}=
    \Bigg[{\begin{matrix}
    \;\;\cos{\theta} & \sin{\theta}  \\
    -\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}  \\
    \end{matrix}}\Bigg]
.$$

I tried multiplying and comparing elements of the products from both sides, but it got complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that what you mean for $A^\tau$ is the transpose, correct?  If so, then notice that $A_\theta^{-1} = A_{-\theta}$, and the constraint that you're imposing is equivalent to

$$
A_\theta X A_\theta \;\; =\;\; X^\tau.
$$

In computing this, notice that if we choose:
$$
X \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c& d \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

then

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
a & c \\
b & d \\
\end{array} \right ] & = & X^\tau \\
& = & A_\theta X A_\theta \\
& = & \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array} \right ]\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c& d \\
\end{array} \right ]\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array} \right ] \\
& = & \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array} \right ]\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
a\cos\theta + b\sin \theta & -a\sin\theta + b\cos\theta \\
c\cos\theta +d\sin\theta & -c\sin\theta + d\cos\theta \\
\end{array} \right ] \\
& = & \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
a\cos^2\theta + b\sin\theta\cos\theta - c\sin\theta\cos\theta - d\sin^2\theta &  * \\
* & * \\
\end{array} \right ].
\end{eqnarray*}

Looking at this last expression we can see that the only value of $\theta$ that could make both sides match is if $\cos^2\theta = 1$.  We therefore are restricted to $\theta = 0,\pi$.  In this case we find that $A_0 = I$ and $A_\pi = -I$ and therefore the only possible matrices $X$ satisfying $A_\theta X = X^\tau A_{-\theta}$ are symmetric matrices, and these can only work for $\theta \in \{\pi k \; | \; k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$